# how to convert completion viewcontroler code from objc into swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures

I need to make init for my view controller in swift. so how can I make similar init method in swift.

```
  - (instancetype)initWithFormlyData:(NSDictionary *)json afterUpdatingProfile:(void (^)(BOOL, BMErrors *))completion

 {

        self = [super initWithFormlyData:json];
if (self) {
    self.updateCompletion = completion;
}
return self;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
init(formlyData json: NSDictionary, afterUpdatingProfile completion: ((Bool, BMErrors?)->Void)?)
    {

    }
```

I took the liberty of making the completion's BMErrors an optional, even though your ObjC didn't specify nullable.  You may have intended other parameters to be nullable too, so add optionals as needed.

You might want to just simplify to:

```
init(json: NSDictionary, completion: ((Bool, BMErrors?)->Void)?)
    {

    }
```

And maybe consider switching to a Swift Dictionary if your caller doesn't mind.

Hope this helps!